Present continuous plus "when"

When I work out I drink a lot.

It's a simple sentence with a simple meaning that during my workouts I drink a lot

When I'm working out I drink a lot.

Same meaning we just emphasize that "working out" is ongoing

When I work out I'm drinking a lot.

Is this correct and has the same meaning as 1 and 2 and here we just emphasize that drinking is ongoing?

Could you please, please, please put a capital letter at the beginning of your sentences and a period at the end of them? Thanks.

@Lambie Sorry, didn't mean to make you so upset haha. Can you now answer my question?

I don't find (3) idiomatic as a way of referring to your typical behaviour in particular circumstances.

@Kate Bunting It means that it doesn't sound natural, right? Still, it is grammatically correct and has almost the same meaning as 1 and 2, right?

Or how do undersntand 3? How is it different to 1 and 2?

#3 isn't remotely idiomatic. You should normally prefer simpler verb forms, so stick with #1, UNLESS you specifically want to dispel a possible ambiguity. The speaker in #1 might mean that sometimes he doesn't work out for many months, then he does work out for months - and he drinks a lot when he's in a "workout" phase (perhaps he drinks too much booze, rewarding himself for diligently working out! :) Note that although #2 more strongly suggests he only drinks (water?) during the specific minutes or hours of working out, either meaning could be conveyed by either verb form.

@FumbleFingers what then my 3 example mean according to you?

The first 2 mean the same, except some people might think "when I'm working" in #2 more strongly implies specifically and only those timeframes within which I'm engaged in the activity. Where #1 could be a more "general" reference - like if you were a freelance consultant hiring out to different employers for weeks or months at a time: "When I'm working for a big company I don't smoke". And #3 means nothing really, except maybe "I'm not a native speaker of English!"

Please provide a link to #3 if you saw it somewhere.  I doubt such word combinations exist.

How come 3 means nothing? It is impossible that only because of using the continuous in the second part it has no meaning and you can't understand that?

@Seowjooheng Singapore . I made it up on my own. Can you tell me what it means to you?

It's meaningless.

Gregor - "Wrong!" Yes, not idiomatic means not a natural way to express something. Three people have now told you that (3) is an invalid sentence which doesn't mean anything.

Agree with everyone BUT: When I work, I'm drinking. When I play piano, I'm smiling. are conceivable.

Why doesn't #3 work? Well, maybe because it doesn't have the reasons for the continuous that #2 had. Let's make the sentence even simpler:

I drink a lot.

With the plain old present tense, this is now very broad in context. Of course, we don't usually say only one sentence at a time, so other sentences might make the context clearer, but by itself this seems to say "In general, over the course of my life, or maybe in recent years, taking it all in average... I drink a lot." (Also, with no other explanation, the meaning usually taken from this is that I drink a lot of alcohol!)
Let's slap a continuous tense on it.

I'm drinking a lot.

Suddenly, this is no longer fit for such a broad context. The present continuous is very "present"; it's for some kind of "right now." It certainly doesn't mean "over the course of my life." It might mean "over the past few years," but only if I've made that context clear already. More likely it means "at this meal," or possibly "right this second (as I stand here at this water fountain)." We don't know the exact context without more help, but there definitely is a context. Using the continuous tense has tied the statement to some present span of time.
In your example #2 you did something similar. You tied the statement about drinking to a specific context. In that case, it didn't have to be our actual present, since you made a "when" clause. But the drinking is tied to that present.
The problem with #3 is that the two contexts fight with each other. "I'm drinking a lot"—by itself, that's a statement about the present that you and I are both in. "When I work out"—that's not. That's a signal that we're talking about a context, a time and place, without having to be in it. Even if you do happen to be working out when saying the sentence, you've made the context broader than this moment; you're saying "every time I work out, including the past and future."
